# C# WebRequest.Create with (:) colon in Uri

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, uri, webrequest

I am having some issue sending an HttpWebRequest when in the Query string there is a `:` and the URI is not escaping it

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://" + _domain + url);
```

the url string can sometimes contain a `:` and this is not escaped resulting for example in the following

```
https://www.bitmex.com/api/v1/order?symbol=XBTUSD&filter=%7B%22open%22:true%7D
```

`WebRequest.Create` accepts a string or an Uri, I can't escape the string before the method otherwise it will be escaped again, and I haven't been able to find how to escape the `:` when the Uri is already created.

Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance

Comment: the url encoding of `:` is `%3A` is check https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: The result is helpful. Seeing the input would be better.

Comment: @Casey I am using this library [link](https://github.com/BitMEX/api-connectors/blob/master/official-http/csharp/BitMEXAPI.cs) but most the code is not relevant

Comment: @Ahmed yes that's right but I can't escate it before I feed it to the Webrequest otherwise it will be escaped twice and I can't escape it when it is already in the Webrequest either

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you don't need to escape `:` in that part of the url. I tested [here](https://developer.azurewebsites.net/csharp-uri-property-values?baseurl=&url=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fapi%2Forder%3A2%3Aabc%3Fa%3D1) and seems to work fine.